# Express ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/index.html'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm having some trouble debugging this issue. Pretty much I have a Node.js that serves a React application and also acts as a REST API. The server runs on port 8080 by default.

```js
import express, {Request, Response} from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import {ENVIRONMENT, PORT} from '../util/secrets';
// Import API Routes
import * as home from './controllers/home';

// Create express server
const app = express();

// Add middleware
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan('combined'));

// Define API routes
app.get('/api/', home.get);

// Configure environment settings
if (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') {
    // ...
} else {
    // Configure Static Files (Production)
    app.use(express.static("./"));

    // Serve React Static Files (Production)
    app.get('*', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/index.html"));
    });
}

// Start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Express started on http://localhost:${PORT}/ in ${ENVIRONMENT} mode.`);
});

export default app;
module.exports = app;
```

Basically I go to localhost:8080 and my app renders just fine. **However** when I go to localhost:8080/login I get the following response from the server:

```sh
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/index.html'
/index.html
```

Here are the morgan logs:

```sh
::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2020:03:01:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64
; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2020:03:01:18 +0000] "GET /app.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost:8080/" "M
ozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
"
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/index.html'
/index.html
::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2020:03:01:20 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404 195 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0
; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
```

Why does it render my app on `localhost:8080` but not `localhost:8080/login`

Dist Folder:

```
dist
  img
  app.bundle.js
  index.html
  server.bundle.js
```

Comment: Is your server running on 3000 or 8080?  You mention both.

Comment: And, what are you expecting to happen when you request `http://localhost:8080/login`?

Comment: @jfriend00 it runs on port 8080, sorry about that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I expect that `http://localhost:8080/login` returns the same result as `http://localhost:8080`. I want the url to have /login so that React Router can pickup the new route and update the current view.

Comment: I wonder if this is induced by webpack?  `http://localhost:8080` works because `express.static()` finds `index.html`, but `http://localhost:8080/login` does not match via `express.static()` so it depends upon your `*` route and perhaps webpack has messed things up somehow.

Comment: @jfriend00 that sounds like it could definitely be the issue. i will probably revisit this in the morning, thank you for your help!

Comment: @jfriend00 Webpack was resolving my __dirname to '/' or root, so it couldn't located my .html file. I then changed resolve to join and it all works now! thank you so much dude

Comment: So, why are you using webpack on server-side code and other server-side resources?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not sure but I built this project to allow for running a dev environment, tests, and build and run a docker environment all from single commands. It saves me a lot of time and makes the build process easier, also webpack helps automate some of my transpiling for me. The architecture is constantly being improved so I'll probably look into removing server stuff from webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webPack is replacing `__dirname` with something else sine webpack is designed to package things differently that your typical file system layout.  I don't quite understand why you're even running webpack on server-side code and resources.

in your `webpack.config.js` add the following:

```js
{
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: false // disables webpack from changing what __dirname does
  },
}
```

Also, `path.resolve()` is not doing what you think it's doing.  It's not really the right choice here, `path.join()` is a better fit.

Change this:

```
path.resolve(__dirname, "/index.html")
```

to this:

```
path.join(__dirname, "/index.html")
```

You could probably make it work with `path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html")`, but I think `path.join()` is the more appropriate choice here.

---

FYI, `path.resolve(__dirname, "/index.html")` results in `"/index.html"` which is not what you want.

Comment: still getting the same error :(, interesting I will look into using .join() versus .resolve() though!

Comment: @jeninja - So, where is `index.html`?  Is it in `__dirname`?  Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder build and copy the build files into this folder

Set the build folder to static

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
```

Then

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: interesting, I think you are on to something here.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occured. What I did was:

a) Put this line in your js file: `const path = require("path")`

b) Join the path when sending the response of the file:

```
app.get("/",function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});
```